# GA4 - First_Tme_User

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to identify first-time user to be identified on GA4 so I can know for example, how many purchases first-time users have made?

Should I create custom dimension to identify first_time users on GA4?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for new users in GA4?

I think there is no need to create a separate report on explore section. You can directly check with Aquisition >> User Aquisition
Filter the event with conversion event
and select First user data

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34325788)